# Code sign error in XCode - is it related to Apple developer site down

Tags: xcode

Today I got Code signing error when building my app in XCode. But when I visited the Apple developer portal, it is redirected to this address: http://devimages.apple.com/maintenance/. Could anyone kindly confirm with me that we need to wait until Apple restore everything to be able to build app in XCode. If you have any workaround for this, it is very great if you can share with me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to download/refresh your code signing identity first then you will not be able to do anything till maintenance is over, otherwise there shouldn't be a problem besides getting the app to the store (what isn't possible cause of the maintenance)

Comment: Peko, all provisioning profiles in my XCode are in "Valid signing identity not found" status so I need to refresh them but I always get timeout error. Is that any workaround to build the app for ad-hoc (I tried to build without code signing but was not succeed).

Comment: This is some kind of BS.